# Importing non-TMY3 format weather data for use in pvlib simulation

Tags: python, pvlib

So I'm busy working on a project where i need to implement a PV system in Python. The best resource for this seems to be the `pvlib` module but I am a bit stuck on getting the appropriate weather data for this.

I need a whole year worth off information for a specific location, in this case Cape Town South Africa.

I am trying to get a `TMY3` file for this, because `pvlib` accommodates this nicely, but the only data I am able to find is only American locations from NREL (https://rredc.nrel.gov/solar/old_data/nsrdb/1991-2005/tmy3/by_state_and_city.html). I can't find a `TMY` for other locations.

Here is the Jupyter notebook tutorial I'm using: https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/pvlib/pvlib-python/blob/master/docs/tutorials/tmy_to_power.ipynb

I found weather data for this location on other sites but they aren't in the format `pvlib` is looking for. Does `pvlib` just accommodate for USA? What options do I have?

Comment: I have no real idea how feasible it would be, but you might be able to convert the weather data for the location from other sites into the format `pylib` supports.

Comment: Hey thanx for the response. Its just that the structure of the TMY3 file that is required by pvlib is really specific. Like all the info in the file is in a specific order and all that kind of stuff. Thats why i thought all TMY3 data files probably has the same structure. But I cant find TMY3 for other countries except for usa that work for pvlib. Is there maybe other ways to get yearly weather summaries to use for a solar panel simulation?

Comment: I don't know of any. There's a link at the bottom of the Wikipedia article on [TMY data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typical_meteorological_year) that says it's for "Weather data for more than 2100 locations worldwide" (although I got a "Service Temporarily Unavailable" when I clicked on it).

Answer (score 2):

pvlib does not care where you get your weather data from or where you want to do your modeling. You've selected an example where pvlib uses TMY data available in the US, but other examples use different data sources and locations. See, for example, the [Intro Tutorial](https://pvlib-python.readthedocs.io/en/stable/introtutorial.html) documentation that uses simulated clear sky data (including a Berlin location). Or the [forecast](https://pvlib-python.readthedocs.io/en/stable/forecasts.html) documentation that uses data from weather forecast models (some US only, but one global). If you can get your data into python, pvlib can use it.

Comment: The first link isn't available anymore. Was it https://pvlib-python.readthedocs.io/en/stable/introtutorial.html ? Also, what is the point of pv simulation with a clear sky model? Berlin's example has a specific energy yield of ~1741kWh/kWp according to the tutorial example, which is almost twice as much as expected, especially since the tilt is high at 50°. I'm probably missing some information, though. Is there a simple example, with realistic weather data and realistic results? Thanks for the hard work BTW. pvlib seems impressive, I just need to learn it correctly.

Comment: Fixed. Thanks. The point is to demonstrate capabilities with simple code. Feel free to submit a pull request to improve it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll try to find the time to write it. And before doing so, I just wanted to make sure it's not hidden somewhere in the documentation or tests. I'll try to calculate the specific yield of a 3kWp pv system somewhere in Europe, with an inverter, weather from pvgis, transposition to POA. Possibly expose the input parameters clearly, so that somebody else could use the code for a quick simulation of their pv system.

Comment: Hello again. I tried to modified the IntroTutorial in order to take weather into account (by downloading data from PVGIS), modified the coordinates a bit and added some reporting code in order to check if the results are plausible.
I'm not sure it would be ready for a pull request, so I pushed to a gist: 
https://gist.github.com/EricDuminil/f646d406967fe965190d2d3fa58df618
Some feedback would be greatly appreciated.